# Including laravel 5 packages in lumen

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

Im currently trying to include illuminate/filesystem into lumen

So far I have managed to install the package running the following command:

```
composer require Illuminate/Filesystem
```

However I have no idea how to register the static class inside the application, I can't seem to find anything on the internet which talks about how to implement laravel 5 packages into lumen.

I have tried adding a class alias to the core of lumen, but this seems wrong to me.

Comment: Why would you need to add the `Illuminate/Filesystem` package when it's already included with Lumen? (http://lumen.laravel.com/docs/filesystem)

Comment: From what i can tell that mainly gives me access to storage, im looking to read files found in the **public folder**. So using File::

Comment: Image files to be exact, found in 'public/images/media'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with registering a class alias for the `File` facade, just don't do it in the framework source files (within the `vendor` directory). A good place to put that is inside the `bootstrap/app.php` file. Just add this and you're good to go:

```
class_alias('Illuminate\Support\Facades\File', 'File');
```

No additional packages need to be installed for this to work because `Illuminate/Filesystem` already comes with Lumen.

Comment: I had a play around and by the looks of things all i need to do is include the following in the controller/seeder i plan to use it in 'use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;'

Comment: Yep, that works as well. The class aliasing just had the added benefit of having the facades in the global namespace, the way the other facades are registered.

Comment: I personally could not get the above to work inside a controller, as it kept erroring out. This was due to it being unable to find file, in the controller namespace. (I think)

Comment: That's because you're in the controller namespace you'd need to prepend the class name with a backslash for it to be in the global namespace: `\File::method()` (but this applies to all the facades). You can read more about this in the [PHP Namespaces Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php).